# Frequently finding the first OrderLine for each Orders

Tags: sql, firebird2.1

Given the OrderLine table below:

```
OrderID    OrderLineID
=======    ===========
  1             1
  1             2
  2             3
  3             4
  1             5
  3             6
 ...           ...
 ...           ...
221 123      365 282
```

What is the most efficient way to find the FIRST OrderLine for each order, given that this information is required to access every now and then by the user?

This is my SQL to find the first OrderLine, but it takes about 3~5 seconds to execute every-time. (about 300k rows)

```
SELECT OrderID, MIN(OrderLineID)
FROM OrderLine
GROUP BY OrderID
```

It's very expensive to repeat this every-time when I need to find the first orderline to join with another table. Consider that changing the table structure is not an option, what possible solution do I have to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an index by OrderID and OrderLineID.

(You say you can't change the table structure. If you were allowed to change the structure, you could add a flag that identifies the first line of every order, then index by that flag.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, however, I should add that index has been created for OrderID and OrderLineID when I post the question on SO.